# Simple MySQL join on varchar(100) fields not working

Tags: mysql

So, I'm making a join for mysql to filter out some bad data and I run into this weird issue.

- Both tables are connected by `payment_transaction_id`.
- They both have the value `3463`.
- A joined result returns no rows.
- Both tables have this value.

Proof that the record is in card_transaction_log:

```
select count(*)
from card_transaction_log 
where payment_transaction_id = 3463;
>> 1
```

Proof that the record is in transaction:

```
select count(*)
from transaction 
where payment_transaction_id = 3463;
>> 1
```

But the join doesn't work.

```
select count(*)
from card_transaction_log a, transaction b
where a.payment_transaction_id = b.payment_transaction_id
and a.payment_transaction_id = 3463;
>> 0
```

Honestly, I've never seen anything like this before in mysql.  I even checked with my colleague to make sure that I wasn't going crazy and/or dumb.

**UPDATE:**

While this is the same as above, this query doesn't work either:

```
select count(*)
from card_transaction_log a
join transaction b
on a.payment_transaction_id = b.payment_transaction_id
where a.payment_transaction_id = 3463;
>> 0
```

Comment: That's... odd. Sanity check: is anything returned if you `SELECT *` rather than `SELECT COUNT(*)`?

Comment: Nope!  Removing count() changes nothing.  I just put in count(*) for the sake of this post (simpler results).

FYI, `a.payment_transaction_id LIKE b.payment_transaction_id` doesn't work either.

Comment: You've got only two records.. what happens when you remove the where clause? And what happens if you add quotes around '3463'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What type is `payment_transaction_id` ? I suspect it is not an INT but a VARCHAR.
If you try to compare a VARCHAR with an INT, MySQL will automatically cast it to an INT but some weird things could happen, eg:

```
'3463' = 3463
```

but also

```
'3463a' = 3463
```

but

```
'3463a' != '3463b'
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdc99/1). You can test your queries like this:

```
select count(*)
from card_transaction_log 
where payment_transaction_id = '3463';
```

and I suspect that at least one of your queries will return 0. Or you can force your join to use the integer value:

```
select count(*)
from card_transaction_log a
join transaction b
on a.payment_transaction_id+0 = b.payment_transaction_id+0
where a.payment_transaction_id = 3463;
```

Comment: They are both `varchar(100)`....  I know varchar is not ideal for id, but hey, I didn't write the thing :-/

Comment: @InsanelyADHD you surely have some values that starts with '3464' but ends with some non-numeric characters

Comment: Ok, so this was the right answer.  One of our newbie programmers did a cut/paste that inserted non-friendly characters into the DB.  In Navicat's Grid View, it cuts off after the first bad character.  Swapping to Form View still didn't show the bad character, but did show the proceeding characters.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this turned out to be because of a hidden character in the data.

I had imported a CSV containing a list of emails using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/temp/users.csv' 
INTO TABLE cloudusers 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 0 ROWS;
```

As a result there was a return character at the end of each VARCHAR.
The strings looked identical but weren't.

When I re-did the import using

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/temp/users.csv' 
INTO TABLE cloudusers 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 0 ROWS;
```

(note the '\r\n' instead of '\n')
the resulting VARCHARs subsequently matched, and all the joins worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
select count(*)
from card_transaction_log a
join transaction b
on a.payment_transaction_id = b.payment_transaction_id
where a.payment_transaction_id = 5081483008;
```

Comment: In mysql those are synonymous.  And, I tried that before posting just to be extra sure.

Comment: Then I am as puzzled as you are on why that would not work.... maybe you can try to replicate it on sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: The schema is valid, it works with other values.  sqlfiddle.com would not help in replicating this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same trouble today and here is what I found out. Even though a SQL select on table A and a SQL select on table B was showing equal values for primary and foreign keys, the values were actually different... a '\n', which was not showing up when the values were displayed in a grid, was the end character of all my foreign key values... 
Root cause, I did not pay attention the file I used to populate my table via 'import' was a corrupted CSV file found on the internet.

you can do a quick test, simply update by hand a few foreign and primary key values that are expected to join and test your query again. If it return results, you found the root cause!